# Codepipeline で作成される成果物のうち、古いものを削除していきたい

Tags: aws

aws の codepipeline を利用しています。

Github -> AWS CodeBuild -> AWS CodeDeploy でもって、コードのデプロイを自動化しています。

このとき、それぞれの入出力に、 S3 の bucket が利用されているのですが、 pipeline が実行されるたびに、成果物が蓄積されていきます。例えば、 master から自動デプロイするような設定にしていた場合には、これを定期的に削除したくなります。

質問

- aws codepipeline で作成されていく成果物を自動で削除していく方法はありますか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://serverfault.com/a/854512/304519 で、この質問に対して回答がなされていました。

aws の s3 は、[オブジェクトのライフサイクル](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/object-lifecycle-mgmt.html) を設定できるので、それを利用して古くなった成果物を削除する設定にすればよい、とのことでした。